# Volume enclosed by plane in 3d

Tags: 3d

> The volume enclosed by the plane $|3x-4|+|2y-3|+|z+4|=3$ is

Try: $$\bigg|x-\frac{4}{3}\bigg|+\frac{2}{3}\bigg|y-\frac{3}{2}\bigg|+\frac{1}{3}\bigg|z+4\bigg|=1$$

Put $\displaystyle x-\frac{4}{3}=X,y-\frac{3}{2}=Y,z+4=Z$

So $$|X|+\frac{|Y|}{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{|Z|}{3}=1.$$

Could some helpe to solve it. Thanks

Comment: It is an octahedron with semi-axis $(a,b,c) = (1,\frac32,3)$ and you can decompose the octahedron into 8 congruent [trirectangular tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trirectangular_tetrahedron) whose volume has the simple formula $\frac16 abc$.

Comment: Thanks achille hue .Then final answer is $\displaystyle 8\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot 1\cdot \frac{3}{2}\cdot 3=$

Comment: Yup, that's the volume.